# I have a question about it in a sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Long journeys by sea were full of danger. Pelias knew that Jason would have to sail through a narrow opening into the Black Sea. Then he had to sail past the jagged rocks that had sent so many boats to the bottom. He might never reach Colchis. If he did, he might never make **it** back alive.

It is a pronoun, but I do not know what it means in this sentence.
He means Jason like if Jason did, Jason might never make **it** back alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*make it back*" and "*make it back alive*" are fixed phrases, meaning "to return successfully". In these phrases "it" is a ***dummy pronoun*** not referring to anything in particular, but required by the structure of the phrase. Or one could say that "it" refers to the journey as a whole, but it is better to say that "it" here is a dummy pronoun.

The word "it" is also a dummy pronoun in:

> - It is raining.
> - It is time to goi.
> - It's going to be a long night
> - It's very dark out there.
> - When it's time. you know it.

and many similar uses.